# Is there a way to set the value for @RequestBody without having to create an object?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote this:

```java
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMetaData> deleteMembers(@PathVariable("group_id") String groupId,
@RequestBody List<String> userIds)
```

But in Postman I can't do it

I fixed it by creating an object UserIds:

```java
public class UserIds {
    @JsonProperty("userIds")
    private List<String> userIds;
}
```

and:

```java
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMetaData> deleteMembers(@PathVariable("group_id") String groupId,
@RequestBody UserIds userIds)
```

But I have one question: Is there any way I can still use `@RequestBody List<String> userIds` ?

Comment: I think this should work. Can you share the Postman request that fails and the error?

Comment: _"But in Postman I can't do it"_. Do you mean you cannot send an array of Strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in postman by this :

```
body/raw/json
```

```json
{
   userIds : [
           "userId1",
           "userId2"
       ]
}
```